# Which tool or method to manage emails with top tagging features?

Tags: database, email

I want to export thunderbird emails with filters, agregate different sources, tag them as it can be performed with blog tags of my choice, sort emails by date, use more filters, extract and output sequences of emails fullfilling some filters that make use of my tags, be able to strip reply parts, etc.

I would prefer a solution where the database where I put the emails is full text as:

```
subject: some subject
from: mr.t@mail.com
to: my@mail.com
cc: someone@mail.com
bcc:
tags: hollidays,family,2015
body: either one line with a special character to separate lines as | this is the 2nd line of the body
```

But one message could be alternatively on one line. The best would be to preserve readability with the layout of the body as in thunderbird.

The database shall offer command line commands or its own shell, but not just a language API.

I have tried the thunderbird import/export plugin to text or text in one file. Metadata are easy to pick, but the body may be anything that breaks shell scripts or make them difficult to design.The csv output is not usefull since it does not put the body in one cell, but each line. Possibly there is a better export plugin (csv or xml) ?

I am preferably looking for a tool that makes this. If I had xml exports, I think I coul use [BaseX](http://basex.org/products/gui/) for example.

I have explored several solutions directions:

- archiver like [piler](http://www.mailpiler.org/en/mailarchiva.html), but the tags do not appear in the search results, I am waiting from upstream answers.
- other email clients like [sup](http://supmua.org/), but it is a CLI solution and not a mature project.
- thunderbirds plugins, but nothing really smarter than the poor tag feature existing already in thunderbird.
- import the emails in a full text database with a mix of database features andscripts : I would like to avoid that !